# How to move retrofit's Callback from Activity to class

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I used to have my  createBottomBar() within Activity. Since Activity passed 4-5 hundreds lines I moved it to a separate class but now I dont know how to access my updateMap().

`updateMap` code is  :

```
private void updateMap(String path) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .build();

    MyService service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
    service.points(path, context);                
}
```

Where the Interface is :

```
public interface MyService {
@GET("/{point}")
void points(@Path("point") String path, MainActivity cb);
}
```

Where/how should I move/change retrofit's Callback so I can keep it working ?

PS : I understand that this is more of a java question than an android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you use for a callback has to implement the `Callback<T>` interface. See here fore more information [Retrofit doc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Callback.html)
So the Callback doesn´t depend on the Activity class but on the implementation of the callback interface. So you can put your `updateMap()` Method in any class you like since it doesnt depend on context. See below for a short example

So your interface might look like this

```
public interface MyService {
    @GET("/{point}")
    void points(@Path("point") String path, Callback<YourClassType>);
}
```

And you can define your callback implementation inline in an anonymous class

```java
MyService service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);

service.points(path, new Callback<YourClassType>)() {
    @Override
    public void success(YourClassType foo, Response response)
    {
        // success
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // something went wrong
    }
});
```

Hope this solves your problem?

EDIT: Please also note, that you don´t have to recreate your Rest Client everytime you want to do a request. It is enough to do that once.
So maybe define a class object for your restclient and reuse it.

```
public class MyRestClientClass{
    //class context
    MyService mService;

    //helper method for service instantiation. call this method once
    void initializeRestClient()
    {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .build();
        mService = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
    }

    //your service request method
    void updateMap()
    {
        mService.points(....)
    }
}
```

To use this class, for example in an activity below is a short dummy code

```java
MyRestClientClass mRestClientClass = new MyRestClientClass();

//instantiate the rest client inside
mRestClientClass.initializeRestClient();

//to call your updateMap for example after a button click 
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //note that this works the same way as the Retrofit callback
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //call your web service
        mRestClientClass.updateMethod();
    }
});
```